# NSPredicate with Underscore Crash

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

```
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"identifer==1_12"];
```

gives me :

```
Unable to parse the format string "identifier==1_12"'
```

I have tried using MATCHES, LIKE, =, with spaces ==, without spaces etc. Somehow I feel the underscore is some kind of a reserved sign.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to compare with the string "1_12", you have to enclose it in single quotes:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"identifer == '1_12'"]
```

Alternatively:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"identifer == %@", @"1_12"]
```